# What is the difference between the below two in csproj file?

Tags: c#, .net, projects-and-solutions

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\WindowsApplication2\WindowsApplication2.csproj">
      <Project>{7CE93073-D1E3-49B0-949E-89C73F3EC282}</Project>
      <Name>WindowsApplication2</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

---

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="WindowsApplication2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <ExecutableExtension>.dll</ExecutableExtension>
      <HintPath>..\WindowsApplication2\bin\Release\WindowsApplication2.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>   
 </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: but, but there's only one? Is this a philosophical question?

Comment: I am new to posting questions in stack overflow!! please bear with me

Comment: It's a good idea to have a read though [help] to get an idea of how and what to ask

Comment: I guess you must be able to see both the scenarios now!! please help me now

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that in one case you have a project reference. It means that Visual Studio includes it as a project, as a code. You can work with it in your solution, you can modify its code. If you change `WindowsApplication2`, then it will be rebuilt and generated DLL-files will be copied to all dependent projects' output folders within solution.

In case 2, you simply have a reference to a generated DLL file. It is a generated assembly, which means no code, no possibility to edit it, no possibility to debug it if there are no .pdb files etc. It also means that you will have to build and update your DLL-file every time you make changes to it.

I may be wrong, but it won't compile if you have both of these references in your project.

Comment: When I click on Reference I can only add DLLs not csproj!! I can add csproj to only solution(sln) file right? can I add csproj to a project and not to a solution?

Comment: @Yaswanth You should read this question [Difference between project and dll dependencies in .Net in the final compiled assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714686/difference-between-project-and-dll-dependencies-in-net-in-the-final-compiled-as)

Comment: and this [VS Solution, projects vs dlls best practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271828/vs-solution-projects-vs-dlls-best-practice)

Comment: @Yaswanth Yes, you need to either include this project into your solution or reference it as DLL.

Comment: @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev : If I include in solution then I will see it as a part of .sln file but I wont see it as a part of csproj but in my project I saw this in csproj and I am not able to figure out what exactly it is

Comment: @Liam : Thanks Liam for the references.